# Angular Google Maps fitBounds

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I can't figure out how to call fitBounds() from an angular-google-maps instance. I'm trying to call it after uiGmapGoogleMapApi resolves but I don't don't know where/how to access this method. From the vanilla js implementation you can call map.fitBounds(bounds) but I'm not sure what the equivalent is in angular-google-maps v2.2.1, thanks for any help.

***Edit***

I got this to work by adding the control property to scope.map and then calling getGMap() when uiGmapIsReady resolves.

```
      uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        scope.bounds = new maps.LatLngBounds();
        scope.map = {
          center: {
            latitude: 47.60427,
            longitude: -122.33825
          },
          zoom: 16,
          polys: [],
          bounds: {},
          control: {} // add this property

        };
        traceVehicle(scope.tripDetails);
      });
      // add uiGmapIsReady and call getGMap()
      uiGmapIsReady.promise(1).then(function(instances) {
        instances.forEach(function(inst) {
          var map = inst.map;
          var uuid = map.uiGmap_id;
          var mapInstanceNumber = inst.instance; // Starts at 1.
          var gMap = scope.map.control.getGMap(); // assign getGMap();
          gMap.fitBounds(scope.bounds);
        });
      });



  function traceVehicle(selectedTrip) {
    var rawPolys = [];
    var polylineObj = {
      id: 1,
      path: [],
      stroke: {
        color: '#6060FB',
        weight: 3
      },
      editable: false,
      draggable: false,
      geodesic: true,
      visible: true
    };
    scope.polylines = [];
    if(selectedTrip.locations.length > 0) {
      angular.forEach(selectedTrip.locations, function(v, i) {
        polylineObj.path.push({ latitude: v.lat, longitude: v.lon });
        scope.bounds.extend({ lat: v.lat, lng: v.lon });
      });
      rawPolys.push(polylineObj);
      scope.map = {
        center: {
          latitude: polylineObj.path[(Math.round(polylineObj.path.length/2) -1)].latitude,
          longitude: polylineObj.path[(Math.round(polylineObj.path.length/2) -1)].longitude
        },
        zoom: 16,
        polys: rawPolys
      };
      scope.map.fitBounds(scope.bounds); // how to call fitBounds()?
```

Comment: `scope.map` is just an object. You want to create  a `google.maps.Map` object for `scope.map`. at least from the snippet you shared...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `$scope.map` to be a google map object. At the moment it's just options.

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    polys: [],
    bounds: {},
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.60427, -122.33825),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
$scope.map.fitBounds(YOUR_CODE_FOR_BOUNDS);
```